# $\frac{x}{x^2-1}$ bijection from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that the function $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1}$ is bijective. I have the following two questions:

1) Proving it using calculus: First I show that $f$ is injective. Since $f'(x) = -\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^2} < 0$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$, then $f$ is monotonic and hence injective.

I am having trouble showing that it is surjective using the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT). The IVT states that if $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $L$ is a real number satisfying $f(a) < L < f(b)$ or $f(b) < L < f(a)$, then there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ where $f(c) = L$. Clearly the function at hand is continuous on $(-1, 1)$, but to use the aforementioned theorem, we need to have a closed interval $[a,b]$ (whereas $(-1, 1)$ is not a closed interval...). I "sort of" have an idea: Since $f$ is continuous on $(-1, 1)$, $f(-1)$ isn't defined but it is basically $+\infty$ and $f(1)$ is "like" $-\infty$, so if $L$ is a real number $-\infty< L < +\infty$, i.e., $L \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists a $c \in (-1, 1)$ such that $f(c) = L$, hence $f$ is surjective. But I feel this is wrong because $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ aren't defined and the IVT needs a closed interval.

2) How can I prove bijection without using calculus? E.g., to show injection, let $\frac{x_1}{x_1^2-1} = \frac{x_2}{x_2^2-1}$ and I want to reach the conclusion that $x_1 = x_2$, but I am stuck. Also, how can I prove surjection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show it is surjective by solving the quadratic equation.  Given $y \in \Bbb R$ we want to find $x$ such that $\frac x{x^2-1}=y$, or $yx^2-x-y=0, x=\frac 1{2y}(1\pm \sqrt{1+4y^2})$ and we want the signs of $x$ and $y$ to be opposite, so we take the minus sign.  The fact that you get a unique answer shows it is injective, so answers your second part as well.

Comment: Thanks. I understand up to the last bit, why do we pick the minus one? I can see from drawing the graph that the plus one does not put $x$ between $(-1,1)$ as required, but how can I show this algebraically? And what do you mean by "we want the signs of x and y to be opposite, so we take the minus sign."? Could you explain a bit more in depth? Thank you!

Comment: Except for the case y=0 which has the unique solution x=0. And when y is not 
 0 I don't understand why you say we want the signs of x,y to be opposite,  but we must take the  minus sign to have |x|<1.

Comment: If you look at the original equation, $x^2-1 \lt 0$ in the region of interest, so $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs.  If we choose the plus sign in the quadratic formula they will have the same sign, so that is not allowed.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:  As often, zero is a special case.  We divide by $y$ in the quadratic formula, so it doesn't work cleanly.  We need the numerator to be zero as well, which again says we want the negative sign.

Comment: Right so in other words, technically we should say $x = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}$ for $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $x=0$ for $y = 0$?

Comment: And any ideas on proving surjection here using IVT instead of using the surjection definition?

Comment: To the O.P. :   $f$ is continuous, with $ f(x)\to -\infty$ as $ x\to 1,$  and $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to -1$  so by the IVT, $ f$  is surjective.

Comment: Thanks but how did you apply the IVT? Don't we need the hypothesis $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ (i.e., continuous on a closed interval), but $f$ is only continuous on $(-1, 1)$ since it's not defined at -1 and 1?

Comment: @user56031: When the limits are infinite that is OK.  To be careful, if you are given a $y$ and want to prove there is an $x$ with $f(x)=y$, you can say there is $x_1$ with $f(x_1) \gt y$ because of one limit and $x_2$ with $f(x_2) \lt y$ because of the limit.  Then your closed interval is $[x_2,x_1]$

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh that makes perfect sense. In other words, you can always find a $[x_2, x_1]$ within the open interval $(-1, 1)$ on which you can apply the IVT!

Answer (score 3):

$$=>x_1x_2^2-x_1=x_2x_1^2-x_2$$
$$=>x_1x_2(x_2-x_1)=-(x_2-x_1)$$
$$(x_1-x_2)(1+x_1x_2)=0$$
$$\text{So, either} \hspace{.2cm}x_1=x_2 \hspace{.2cm} or  \hspace{.2cm} x_1=-\frac{1}{x_2}.$$
The last equality is not possible due to the domain $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1-x}).$
$-1 < x < y < 1 \implies \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1+y} = \frac{y - x}{(1+x)(1+y)} > 0.$
$-1 < x < y < 1 \implies -\frac{1}{1-x} - (-\frac{1}{1-y}) = \frac{-(1-y)+(1-x)}{(1-x)(1-y)} = \frac{y-x}{(1-x)(1-y)} > 0.$

$\therefore$
$-1 < x < y < 1 \implies \frac{x}{x^2-1} > \frac{y}{y^2-1}.$

$\therefore f$ is injective.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1+0} f(x) = +\infty.$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-0} f(x) = -\infty.$$

There is $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $-1 < x < -1 + \delta_1 \implies f(x) < y$.

There is $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $1 - \delta_2 < x < 1 \implies y < f(x)$.

Let $-1 < a < -1+\delta_1$ and $1-\delta_2 < b < 1$.

Then $f(a) < y < f(b)$.

$f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

So by the intermediate-value theorem, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c) = y$.

$\therefore f$ is surjective.